# I need some sort of paint enviroment to rotate images

Tags: rotation, paint, environment, image-rotation, paint.net

Recently I downloaded paint.net. It can rotate images in every angle.
I need 360 images, each rotated different angle, with appropriate filename (1.jpg, 2.jpg etc).
The problem is- on paint.net I must rotate it 360 times manually which would take me forever.

Is there any sort of enviroment to rotate images the way I want?
I need this because I want to load the 360 images into a game in c++ and thats how I will rotate the images.

Answer (score 0):

If you do it for a game, why wouldn't you write your own program that does it for you? Its the simpliest way.

For example check this simple python script:

```
# Make sure to install PIL after your regular python package is installed

import Image

image = Image.open("yourpicture.jpg")
for (a in range(360)):
     image2 = image.rotate(a)
     image2.save(str(a) + "jpg")
     del image2
```

There's no such a tool in paint.net, but you can try writing your own plugin (check CodeLab plugin).